# FreeCodeCamp: Record Collection return "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays

The challenge is "Basic JavaScript: Record Collection" from Freecodecamp. The challenge is to update the Record Collection which is in JSON format.

Here's the code that I wrote:

```js
var collection = {
  "2548": {
    "album": "Slippery When Wet",
    "artist": "Bon Jovi",
    "tracks": [
      "Let It Rock",
      "You Give Love a Bad Name"
    ]
  },
  "2468": {
    "album": "1999",
    "artist": "Prince",
    "tracks": [
      "1999",
      "Little Red Corvette"
    ]
  },
  "1245": {
    "artist": "Robert Palmer",
    "tracks": []
  },
  "5439": {
    "album": "ABBA Gold"
  }
};
// Keep a copy of the collection for tests
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));


// Only change code below this line
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if (prop !== "tracks" && value !== "") {
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  } else if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {
    collection[id][prop].push(value);
  } else if (value == "") {
    delete collection[id][prop];
  } else if (prop === "tracks") {
    collection[id][prop] = [value];
  }


  return collection;
}

// Alter values below to test your code
updateRecords(5439, "artist", "ABBA");
```

It meets all the requirements except for one requirement:

> After updateRecords(5439, "tracks", "Take a Chance on Me"), tracks
>   should have "Take a Chance on Me" as the last element.

When I checked the console, I got this statement

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

It seems that the code thinks that `push` (which should be a function) is actually an object property.

How do I fix it?

If you want to read more about this challenge in details, here's the link:
https://guide.freecodecamp.org/certifications/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/record-collection/

Comment: *"It seems that the code thinks that push (which should be a function) is actually an object property."* Not quite. It things you're trying to get the property `push` from `undefined`, which tells you that `collection[id][prop]` is resulting in `undefined`. So your best bet is to debug that with the debugger built into your IDE or browser, by setting a breakpoint on that line and figuring out why `prop` isn't a valid property name for `collection[id]` (or is, but the property value is `undefined`). (Hint: Look at the entry for 5439, and the `prop` you're passing into `updateRecords` for it.)

Comment: `5439` doesn't have a `tracks` array. So, you need to check if `collection[id][prop]` is undefined first. If yes, you need to assign `collection[id][prop] = []` before pushing a `value` to  it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, your code will never reach the `else if (prop === "tracks")` condition. If `prop === "tracks"` , it will go to the `prop === "tracks" && value !== ""` condition and try to push `value` to `tracks` array. If the `tracks` array doesn't exists for an `id`(5439 for example), it will throw the error. So, you can change the condition as the following

Check if the property is `tracks`. Inside this `if` condition check if `collection[id][prop]` has value or not. If yes, push it to the array. Else, add a new array like this `[value]`

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {

    // check if tracks exists
    if (collection[id][prop])
      collection[id][prop].push(value)
    else
      collection[id][prop] = [value]; // create a new array

  } else if (value != "") {
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  } else if (value == "") {
    delete collection[id][prop];
  }

  return collection;
}
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var collection={2548:{album:"Slippery When Wet",artist:"Bon Jovi",tracks:["Let It Rock","You Give Love a Bad Name"]},2468:{album:"1999",artist:"Prince",tracks:["1999","Little Red Corvette"]},1245:{artist:"Robert Palmer",tracks:[]},5439:{album:"ABBA Gold"}};

// Keep a copy of the collection for tests
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

// Only change code below this line
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {
  
    if(collection[id][prop])
      collection[id][prop].push(value)
    else
      collection[id][prop] = [value]
  
  } else if (value != "") {
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  } else if (value == "") {
    delete collection[id][prop];
  }

  return collection;
}

// Alter values below to test your code
updateRecords(5439, "artist", "ABBA");
updateRecords(5439, "tracks", "Take a Chance on Me");

console.log(collection[5439])
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the same answer as the one in the link I provide. I actually was trying to write the code before looking at the solution in that link. I just want to improve my analytics/programming skills.